# Remove all optional items from a Tuple type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let say I want to turn a tuple with optional items like `[1, 2, 3?, 4?]` to an array containing only the required items -> `[1, 2]`

What i've come up with as shown below it to turn to never all optional items, and I'm stuck here.

```js
type OnlyReq <L extends any []> = {
  [K in keyof L]-?: L [K] extends Required <L> [K]  ? L [K] : never
}

type Found = OnlyReq <[1, 2, 3?, 4?]> // [1, 2, never, never]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxAJQgRygHgDJQgD2AjgBMBnKAQzhCgG0BdAPigF4oBvAWACgp6A0lACWcKAGsIIAPYAzKNgYBaAPwAuBYIZ5CxclFRoArsIBOEElmws6A7VBWbb2jXAgA3CKd4BfXr1BIKAAxaSNSNlhEFHQsOgBGABooACZkgGYVZIAWFWYoAHoC%20iTU5LdPU3KPLwYgA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLLoZm) meet your needs?  (Please test against any use cases / edge cases you care about).  If so I can write up an answer; if not, please let me know what I'm missing (preferably by [edit]ing the question with an example of an unmet need)

Comment: Also, you should probably edit the question and title to refer to "[tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)" instead of "array".

Comment: @jcalz yep it does the job ;). Thanks a lot. The use case is to be able to know the length of the parameters of a function - disregarding optional arguments. By the way in order to avoid another question would you know, for the same purpose a way to discard rest parameters ? I can edit the question if you prefer

Comment: @jcalz I should have test your solution has it already answer my second uses case. Perfect solution. Could you write the answser so I can validates it ? thanks again - could you explain a tad the type u've designed ?

Comment: @jcalz the part I do not get in your definition is: how di you know that the infer type `F` is not an optional type ?

Comment: I'm going to explain in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My approach here would be to write a [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) (actually [tail recursive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) so it will work for quite long tuples in TS4.5+) that walks through the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) until it finds that the rest of it is *all optional*.

Note that [optional elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) cannot be followed by required elements; that is, something like `[1, 2?, 3]` is impossible.  So if a tuple has *any* required elements, the first element in particular must be required.

Here's an implementation:

```
type OnlyReq<T extends any[], U extends any[] = []> = Partial<T> extends T ? U :
  T extends [infer F, ...infer R] ? OnlyReq<R, [...U, F]> : U
```

We are accumulating the result in the type parameter `U` (which starts off as the empty tuple `[]`), so as soon as we decide to stop iterating we return `U`.

The check `Partial<T> extends T` uses [the `Partial<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to come up with an all-optional version of the input tuple.  Generally speaking `T extends Partial<T>` is true but `Partial<T> extends T` is not, unless `T` is already the same as `Partial<T>`... in other words, `Partial<T> extends T` if and only if `T` is all-optional.

If the tuple `T` is all-optional then we return `U`.  Also if `T` is empty we return `U` (which is what happens if `T` can't be split into a first element `F` and a rest tuple `R`).  If `T` has a first element `F`, then we know it's required (otherwise `T` would be all-optional), and we can just push it onto the end of the `U` tuple for the recursive call for the rest of the tuple `R`.

---

Let's see if it works:

```
type Found = OnlyReq<[1, 2, 3?, 4?]>
// type Found = [1, 2]
```

Looks good.

Also note that [rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types) are also considered "optional" in this same test, so they should also be stripped:

```
type StripRest = OnlyReq<[string, boolean?, ...number[]]> 
// type StripRest = [string]
```

Indeed, a non-tuple array type (`Foo[]`) is equivalent to tuple consisting of just a rest element (`[...Foo[]]`) and so would be transformed to an empty tuple, which may or may not be what you want:

```
type Hmm = OnlyReq<number[]>
// type Hmm = []
```

I'm considering ["leading" or "middle" rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) to be out of scope here, since they do weird things and you didn't ask about them (and I hope it doesn't come up because it's annoying to manipulate such types):

```
type What = OnlyReq<[...string[], number]>
// type What = []
type AlsoWhat = OnlyReq<[string, ...boolean[], number]>
//type AlsoWhat = [string]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdgGxAJQgRwDwBUoQB7ARwAmAzlAIZwgDaAugDRQCquBRZl19UAvFPQB8fKAAUKAJ2ABLCgmzD8hEuRwB+FlABcAWABQUKDiUdyNaXABmECVABiTAHTOL128jpQN8JKkzImGmdHZiY7OmEtFn19UEh7AHsAVxIRHxR0DBoARiYAJiYAZjUmABY1CP0AeiqoOOg7ZNT+HPy6WPBoAGVgCWkwVFJgNMQMzBohvrgAcyYAIwSEhAgqEqhguCSAWzmbekq9GrrOqB6+gYghkQnei2n2vXqoAAktrZHfTM2dvYOjp9e7xaDw68QA6gALCjDfjpPxZYKTO70JjfXYSP61J6Q6HXB5PACCCFICRxMNgo3hNyms3WzgWSxWcBRUDRNkxhOJpKh5OpdxBeiAA)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot