# How to make compiler complain at definition on an invalid type instead complaining while type is used

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The aim is to define a Function type that only accept a certain amount of mandatory parameters.

Thanks to @jcalz who [helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70684030/remove-all-optional-items-from-a-tuple-type/70685638#70685638) define the type `OnlyTupleRequired` which allow to remove any optional arguments and thus far allow to know the length of the parameters even when they includes optional ones, I've managed to do it.

Now I would like the compiler to complain at the definition of a function not at the use of them - any comment stating 'should error' should emit an error and don't.

Here's the link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwDIBo4EE0DkC%20cBmUEIcA5DAM4C0MEEANgEYCm9MpAUBzAJ5jNwA8gDt6PACoBXMPWYAlZgEdJwKMwAmcADzi4zAB4xmw9RThIAdEmAUYaAKp7Dx0%20as34AXjgBtALoAfHDeCBxwcAAMAFxwugZGJmY%20wML4zFBwAGJoFrkAFClpGXIAlH5wAPxCohLSsgrKqhracmg%20uRb2aJmBcDH2YXAAjP0ceD7oFgCizonaAAoAhrDAi-Ta4gFom35cvPxwALKL%20ktQiyDMRlAUAMIQksJecABMe3wCmY8AxjDAEMJdFp5k4Eq5LNZbME4IthDw0HJobCeEEQoMRnA8h0wMsLhQYvMSsEgnJBtE4MJmAA3dJjXxYKwQADu6Smim0EOMAHMYAALbQiMRSGTyJQqNSaYEBLZHE5nC5XdJ3B5PAK7DjqZjfejLATfAFQ-Dkr7CX7-QHhS1W6028IAejtcAovIe9E0LExRM8QWRGq1OrUcH1wkNEQgMRNZoBQJ8QwqvVtNodTpdkjdcA9eUWMTjXp9cL92t1QYN8CNUAjPz%200e0Q38QUTScdztd7oEWNy2eGvj8eZhBc1RcDwcNGMj1YtWljCcb1uTLbTbcxXaGfd9g4DetLBCG4ayVfNMaGaDjM8T89T6czK7QjAqObXA-9xZHZaGFf3ponR5yuTrfjPS0L1bDN2xvOAOkYHMe0fHhC03EsQzLF5Ky-Q9tFjE9APPZtLyXLMc1vB9iX7OCNxfbd8BePdx3Qqdj2GE94wbJsUxA69CIzTjvnvYZYPgiikIIF4P1omt6JPX8LH-M9gMXUDl04qDGKDXjVxI9dn2HSiAGZUKjSdMJUoZsKtZN1GATRhAgeB0iIDImV5YBZCcfgzWELk4ABZgBO0oT8B0miD3EoyGLC5i50dCyrJsvQoHsuBHOcgQDDcv4PK8ylfK3fydNE4LDLCySIL-fxenMyyKViuzoESpyXNSrV0s87yuCNT1Z06rrOuTJloAAazMRYzEa34NA4I0IA67qZtm3qBqGkb9DS8by2m2aNtneaoEGmElpW9QJqGTF1M2s7bW23bhtcprVt3E6TyJc7zsuxabrGw78HfB7jKe56Ztevb3qMT6Xh%2007-s2wHrtGkGJuo8HHshgHHT6na3th1aRMR37ka21GFqBzHPp0nGIbx-G4oSmHltuzRSEpGkMl5a7rKDNZ1goYAuQ6TgAqmvIir4imesdGqMhpg6yEZ9I4BZsw2e%20DmnW53mJrysm-pFi6xfi2rJbp6XqVl%20WqvZ%20hOdV3JOCAA)

```js
import {L, A, N} from 'ts-toolbelt'

type OnlyTupleRequired <T extends L.List, U extends L.List = []> = {
  0: T extends [infer F, ...(infer R)] ? OnlyTupleRequired <R, [...U, F]> : U
  1: U
} [A.Extends <Partial <T>, T>]

type MaxParametersCount = 2

type FunctionT <P extends L.List = any, R = any> = {
  1: (...params: P) => R
  0: never
} [N.LowerEq <L.Length <OnlyTupleRequired <P>>, MaxParametersCount>]

declare const f0: FunctionT                     // should be () => any
declare const f0o: FunctionT<[1?]>              // should be (a: 1?) => any
declare const f0r: FunctionT<1[]>               // should be (...a: 1 []) => any
declare const f1: FunctionT<[1]>                // should be (a: 1) => any
declare const f1o: FunctionT<[1, 1?]>           // should be (a: 1, b?: 1) => any
declare const f1r: FunctionT<[1, ...1[]]>       // should be (a: 1, ...b: 1 []) => any
declare const f2: FunctionT<[1, 1]>             // should be (a: 1, b: 1) => any
declare const f2o: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1?]>        // should be (a: 1, b: 1, c?: 1) => any
declare const f2r: FunctionT<[1, 1, ...1[]]>    // should be (a: 1, b: 1, c?: 1) => any
declare const f3: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1]>          // did not error while expecting one
declare const f3o: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1, 1?]>     // did not error while expecting one
declare const f3r: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1, ...1[]]> // did not error while expecting one

f0 ()                                           // works as expected
f0o ()                                          // works as expected
f0r ()                                          // works as expected
f1 (1)                                          // works as expected
f1o (1, 1)                                      // works as expected
f1r (1, 1, 1)                                   // works as expected
f2 (1, 1)                                       // works as expected
f2o (1, 1, 1)                                   // works as expected
f2r (1, 1, 1, 1)                                // works as expected
f3 (1, 1, 1)                                    // error as expected 'never has no call sig...'
f3o (1, 1, 1)                                   // error as expected 'never has no call sig...'
f3r (1, 1, 1)                                   // error as expected 'never has no call sig...'
```

Comment: "I'm not able to provide a playground".  Consider simplifying your question until you can.  The particulars of ts-toolbelt and number literals is how you ran into the problem, but they are not the problem itself, right?  Anything that lowers the bar for others to engage with the problem will help you, so the effort should be worth it to you.  Note that `Function` is a built-in type so unless your question is about how to shadow built-in types, you should use a different name.

Comment: I'm not sure to be able to have it working without `LowerEq`,  so I'm afraid I won't be able to do that :/. Yep Function was just used for testing it won't be the final name. I'll try yo provide a playground (maybe jsfiddle ?).

Comment: @jcalz I've been able to provide a playground (on sandbox)

Comment: You can indeed make it [as a playground](https://tsplay.dev/NaYo6N). TSPlayground lets you import types for published libraries (but not the actual libraries, so nothing at runtime)

Comment: thank you didn't know that: updated

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WzLzEN) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer (although I've got a backlog of these so it could be a while).  If not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @jcalz this is exactly what I Wanted!! Just a quick question, not that I want it but I don’t get why I can’t initiate `P & C` with `[]` ? I didn’t know that I could constrain generic types with the `&` operators - and every time I read one on your answer I learn something new… just amazing and a  big thank you! Could I ask you three not relevant to this much broader question about typescript ? Will be glad to read your answer when you’lll make it :)

Comment: @jcalz While trying to build a 'clean' version I came at a problem as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w6XKGm) - I understand why it breaks (as `P` is constraints by  `C`) but is there a way to go around that issue to provide a type that is with annotations easy to understand ?

Comment: "is there a way to go around that issue" <-- not that I know of.   "to provide a type that is with annotations easy to understand" <-- I don't follow, sorry.

Comment: what I ment is to have a type that when used will show on over in editor `TFunction <Params extends any [], Result = any>` instead of showing the complex signature that we do get from the type.

Comment: No, it will show `C` no matter what, but you could make it less awful with a type alias like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJRZlW).  I am not going to focus on this in my answer, though.  Side question; what are you doing with `{0: XX; 1: YY}[ZZ]`?  That looks like the sort of thing that was necessary before recursive conditional types were supported; what's wrong with `ZZ extends 0 ? XX : YY`?

Comment: nothing wrong with that form - just a preference ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your definition of `FunctionT<P, R>` doesn't prevent a "bad" `P` from being assigned to it.  The only [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) you have is `L.List` (something specific to ts-toolbelt which is, I guess, just `ReadonlyArray<any>` ‍♂️).  But you specifically care about making sure that it has at most two required parameters (or something like it).  So you want to ensure both `P extends L.List` and that `N.LowerEq<OnlyTupleRequired<P>["length"], MaxParametersCount> extends 1`.  Currently you are having `FunctionT<P, R>` evaluate to `never` if the latter check isn't true.  But maybe we can rewrite the definition so that `P` is actually constrained:

```
type FunctionT<P extends (
    N.LowerEq<OnlyTupleRequired<P>["length"], MaxParametersCount> extends 1
    ? L.List : never
) = any, R = any> = (...params: P) => R
```

That happnens to be accepted; sometimes the compiler will get unhappy about circular constraints (where `P` appears in the constraint directly), in which case you can sometimes (ab)use [generic parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to circumvent such issues:

```
type FunctionT<
    P extends L.List & C = any,
    R = any,
    C = N.LowerEq<OnlyTupleRequired<P>["length"], MaxParametersCount> extends 1
      ? unknown : never
    > = (...params: P) => R
```

But in this case it's not necessary.

---

Let's make sure this does what you want:

```
declare const f0: FunctionT; // okay
declare const f0o: FunctionT<[1?]>; // okay
declare const f0r: FunctionT<1[]>; // okay
declare const f1: FunctionT<[1]>; // okay
declare const f1o: FunctionT<[1, 1?]>; // okay
declare const f1r: FunctionT<[1, ...1[]]>; // okay
declare const f2: FunctionT<[1, 1]>; // okay
declare const f2o: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1?]>; // okay
declare const f2r: FunctionT<[1, 1, ...1[]]>; // okay
declare const f3: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1]>; // error
declare const f3o: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1, 1?]>; // error
declare const f3r: FunctionT<[1, 1, 1, ...1[]]>; // error
```

Looks good.  The working versions continue to function as expected.  The three bad versions give you compiler errors right at the definition site.  Note that the type itself does not evaluate to `never` anymore, so if you go on to use `f3`, `f3o`, or `f3r` you won't necessarily get additional errors:

```
f3(1, 1, 1); // no error
```

If you must, you can do both tricks so that the output type is `never` as well.  But personally I think that the compiler error at the definition of `f3` means that anything you do with `f3` afterward is suspect and if it happens not to give an additional error it's not a big deal.  Up to you, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgGQDRwILoHJwL5wBmUEIcARDAM4C0MEEANgEYCmjM5A3AFA8wBPMKzgB5AHaMBAFQCuYRqwBKrAI6zgUVgBMAPNLisAHjFbjtVFADpkwKjHQBVQybMXrt+3AC8cANoAugB8Pog8cBFwAAwAXHAGxqbmln7A4oSsUHAAYuhW+QAUaRlZSgCUAXAA-GKSMvKKKuqaOrpK6H75Vo7o2cFwcY68kXAAjIO8eH4YVgCirsm6AAoAhrDAK4z6QejSQQG8-EIiALIrRqtQKyCsplBUAMIQsuLwvgBMhwD0AFRwgsIci8AMYwYAQcTSZYuJLuZA2OxvOArcQCdBKUIogQhXwIcJjOIFLpgNbXKhxJZlHwhJT42JwcSsABumR4BD82BsEAA7plZqo4Lp4cgzABzGAAC0FEikcgUyjUGi02kFSyCOzgZwupJud0ez1e+3CPy+fABImyILBEKhSxhbksBXxEU5yB5fNUuhl9XlTSVrTVfnIinE4ol5AC6C1l2ut0y+peMBCiQdY2d1Q8iIGDOZrKpvix6MxqJxcCJ+RJVxA5LglOpcFpPF+-2OQPEoPBkN06btKeSma8ADI4A9i2j0xiC6jUOnR75Xe6oPyvXU5Y1FS09IHg2LJRGo+cY7r409E8mFu5RhmXgBrcQ88TZxksqDp0vlqyVskU-M0ngmvhtFYYFGDWERgQhLxCHpS122tSEuDgL4vjgCAbxWAQeCAkCwLgCDxCgqIIDiWCOxtXQ-FGKpgkQ5DUPQzDsNArQ8Mg+BoKgEirU7KFRkCIJaJQtCMKw4DmPAtiiHGNsyK7SiaKQoSGNEnCWPwqDRmImT4KhSj0CohS6OExixNw9T2NGTjtJ4ijRjyfI+ICQylJEpizMkwh3i4uCbL0sZnPo1zTLUjz3i00idNs-T9OogTFMCkzVIkgj2PeKyIt8uyxnsqxHIC4yVPE1iUqIABmbzZN0rLqoCzISFfNyQpKwhSvC7jyL86qYtqqB6sK9zmtK9L2rkrrsrgLo8riui6ugPhoIKMpBLgbloBvSwVksYxhFBHQeGgiBFuW1aoHW5EtqMHbTG0faoigI74pOs7NpcK69sIUYClGJbHrWjaLrem6PsO6qfrop7-te4Drv2yyvuisYwZQiHzqh3agfeeHEeOv7Ue26H3rCrHQZx07Ifx9H9rS4mEe+0nnoBgmbv20qaex+L70MXq5qAA)

Comment: Thank you so much ! Is it common to abuse of generic default ? And for instance to uses them a little like vars for storing a transformation on a generic such as type `MyType <T, TT = Transform <T>> = // ... Multiple use of TT in the type` in order to reduce complexity of reading in the type. Is it ok or bad practice ?

Comment: Off-brand use of generic defaults isn't *uncommon*; if they can be avoided without making things crazy I tend to avoid them.  Sometimes they're the simplest way to write something.