# `never` not assignable yet accepted as generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I wonder why the `never` type is accepted as input in generic's extended types.

For instance:

```
type Pluralize <A extends string> = `${A}s`

type Working = Pluralize <'language'>   // 'languages' -> Work as expected
type WhyIsItWorking = Pluralize <never> // never       -> Resolves and don't complain
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgVwE4EM4EsBe0A8BBKCAD2AgDsATAZyiuCXTIHMA%20KAXigAMASAbzwBfKlwBQo0JCgB1APZIA1oyYdYiVBmxQcAcjgpmCFEwg62UKAHpLUPQaZGTVHVAC0bOYqgoaxSAGNSCglwaGkACxAASSoo4E8lZlV4ZDQsXDIIADcIJDZrKEycpAtSi3coACUIKlk4HJoAIwRgKApZMh1W-1kAWzB9RiA)

Does someone knows a comprehensive answer, and/or is they re a good tutorial on the `never` type ?
For what've seen in the official doc is that `never` is [never assignable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#any-unknown-object-void-undefined-null-and-never-assignability)...

Finally if I want the ts compiler to complain when input is invalid what is the correct pattern to use ?

Comment: For the same reason you can do `type MyNever = never;` ? It does seem weird.

Comment: There is no way to make TS trhrow a compilation error in this particular representation. The closes workaround is [this](https://tsplay.dev/Ndj40W)

Comment: Nice solution @captain-yossarian, but no way to achieve that on the tyoe definition itself? I've tried adding constrain in the type definition itself [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688220/how-to-make-compiler-complain-at-definition-on-an-invalid-type-instead-complaini/70705613#70705613) but it don't work here - do. you know why ? I'm guessing I'm missing something on the `never` type ...

Comment: don't get what ur telling @JuanMendes. could you elaborate please ?

Comment: @zedryas AFAIK, there is no way to achieve it in standalone type representation.

Comment: [This](https://catchts.com/type-negation) article might be useful if you want to negate types

Comment: @captain-yossarian what is this pattern that you did use in the comment ` [T] extends [never]` is for ? how come `T extends never` is not sufficient ?

Comment: `[T] extends [never]` disables [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Please see last example in the docs.  `T extends never` is not sufficient, please see [example](https://tsplay.dev/we4ngW). `T` distributes over the `never` and because `never` is an empty union, `T` does not go through conditional branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`never` extends *everything*. To get a feel for why, it may help to think of types as being sets.

Consider the code `A extends string`. If we're thinking in sets, then this means "A is a subset of `string`". `string` is the set of all possible strings (so "a", "aa", "aaa", etc). A type like `"a" | "b"` extends from `string`, because the set with elements "a" and "b" is a subset of the set of all possible strings. A type like `"a" | 2` does not extend from `string`, because it has an element (`2`) which `string` does not have, making it not a subset of `string`.

So what set is `never`? It's the empty set. There are no values in the set. This is why it's impossible to assign to `never`, because no value exists which work for it. But because it's the empty set, it is, by definition, a subset of every other set. Therefore, it extends from everything.

> Finally if I want the ts compiler to complain when input is invalid what is the correct pattern to use ?

You won't be able to ban `never` from this type, but i'm not sure why you'd need to. While the type `Pluralize<never>` is legal, it's not possible to construct something that matches that type. For example, if i had a function like this:

```
function test<T extends string>(val: Pluralize<T>) {
  // ... 
}
```

... and was trying to call `test<never>(/* insert argument here */)`, there is no possible argument i could put in my function call which typescript would allow.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's definitely a bit clearer - I will validate your answer if no other comes - and I'll start from here. The issue with letting `never` go through is when you build complex type that relies on other types suddenly having some never that can occurs is a headache

Comment: So there's no real world use for `test<never>()`?

Comment: Unless you're doing type assertions, there isn't a way to write code that calls `test<never>`. You could conceivably write some *unreachable* code which calls `test`, and by virtue of being unreachable it could have type `test<never>`. But then it's not actually being used.

Comment: @NicholasTower i've adde your example in the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoDJ8w) but the result is really annoying. not having never as a result could let me propagate the error further down - and that's a reason why I'm trying to find a way to have the compiler complains about a bad input  ...